# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in my socket.IO JS File

Tags: javascript, websocket

So i just started with Socket.io and was creating a simple web based chat by going through their docs.

Now, My javascript is short and I have been starring at my code for a while but couldn't figure out this error

```
chat.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is my JS

```
//Make Conection
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

//references to different thing here
var messsage = document.getElementById("message");
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var output1 = document.getElementById('output');
var btn = document.getElementById("send");

//Emit events
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  socket.emit("chat", {
    message: messsage.value,
    handle: handle.value
  });
});

//receiving message from server and display it to the HTML
socket.on('chat', function(data){
  console.log(data);
  output1.innerHTML += "<p> <strong>" data.handle "</strong> </p>"
})
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error here in concatenation string:

```
 output1.innerHTML += "<p> <strong>" data.handle "</strong> </p>"
```

Fixed:

```
output1.innerHTML += "<p> <strong>" + data.handle + "</strong> </p>"
```